# How to open multiple ports dynamically using TcpNetServerConnectionFactory in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

Right now i'm using the below code to start socket connection for Single port, how can i achieve it for multpile ports dynamically ?

```
 @Bean
 public TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf() { 
     TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(9999);
     cf.setSingleUse(true);
     cf.setSerializer(codec());
     cf.setDeserializer(codec());
     return cf; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dynamic flow registration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows) to create multiple servers programmatically.

```java
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(IntegrationFlowContext context, MessageChannel tcpChannel) {
    return args -> {
        IntStream.of(1234, 1235).forEach(port -> {
            IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(Tcp.netServer(port))
                    .outputChannel(tcpChannel))
                    .get();
            context.registration(flow).register();
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure that `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` with `0` for port. Operation system will choose a random available port then for you. To get that port you need to perform `getPort()` or `getServerSocketAddress()`. See Docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#overview.

`isListening()` check could be used to wait until connection factory is really ready on the selected port.